# Unhandled Rejection (Error) in ReactJS, implementing files causes error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement some search features for an online book store with reactjs. I found a good repo that uses the google book api and decided to implement it on my project to see how it would work. But I'm getting the following error: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Ewl.png)

my github is: https://github.com/luismir15/CEN4010.git *branch: luis*

```js
//code implemented by jason rivera
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BookList from './BookList';
import SearchBox from './SearchBox';
import request from 'superagent';

class Books extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            books: [],
            searchField: '',
            sort: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        request
            .get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes")
            .query({ q: this.state.searchField })
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({ books: [...data.body.items] })
            })
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        request
            .get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes")
            .query({ q: this.state.searchField })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({ books: [...data.body.items] })
        })
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ searchField: e.target.value })
    }

    handleSort = (e) => {
        this.setState({ sort: e.target.value});
    }


    render() {
        const filteredBooks = this.state.books.sort((a, b) => {
            const price1 = a.saleInfo.hasOwnProperty('listPrice') == false ? "$0.00" : a.saleInfo.listPrice.amount;
            const price2 = b.saleInfo.hasOwnProperty('listPrice') == false ? "$0.00" : b.saleInfo.listPrice.amount;
            if(this.state.sort == 'Newest'){
                console.log("in newest")
                return parseInt(b.volumeInfo.publishedDate.substring(0, 4)) - parseInt(a.volumeInfo.publishedDate.substring(0, 4));
            }
            else if(this.state.sort == 'Oldest'){
                return parseInt(a.volumeInfo.publishedDate.substring(0, 4)) - parseInt(b.volumeInfo.publishedDate.substring(0, 4));
            }
            else if(this.state.sort == 'High'){
                return parseInt(b.volumeInfo.averageRating) - parseInt(a.volumeInfo.averageRating);
            }
            else if(this.state.sort == 'Low'){
                return parseInt(a.volumeInfo.averageRating) - parseInt(b.volumeInfo.averageRating);
            }
            else if(this.state.sort === 'Expensive'){
                return parseInt(price2) - parseInt(price1);
            }
            else if(this.state.sort === 'Cheap'){
                return parseInt(price1) - parseInt(price2);
            }
          return;
        })

        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <SearchBox 
                    data={this.state} 
                    handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} 
                    handleChange={this.handleChange} 
                    handleSort={this.handleSort}
                />
                <BookList books={filteredBooks}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Books;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BookCard from './BookCard';


const BookList = (props) => {
    return (
      <div className="list">
        {
          props.books.map((book) => {
            return <BookCard key={book.id} info={book} />
          })
        }
      </div>

    );
}

export default BookList;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const SearchBox = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className="search-area">
        <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
            <input onChange={props.handleChange} placeholder="Search books" type="text"/>
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
            <select value={props.sort} onChange={props.handleSort}>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Sort</option>
                <option value="Newest">Newest</option>
                <option value="Oldest">Oldest</option>
                <option value="High">High to Low</option>
                <option value="Low">Low to High</option>
                <option value="Expensive">$$$-$</option>
                <option value="Cheap">$-$$$</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        </div>

    );
}

export default SearchBox;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


const BookCard = (props) => {
    const { volumeInfo } = props.info;
    const { saleInfo } = props.info;
    const {title, authors, averageRating, subtitle, publishedDate} = props.info.volumeInfo;
    const price = saleInfo.hasOwnProperty('listPrice') == false ? "$0.00" : saleInfo.listPrice.amount;
    const thumbNail = volumeInfo.hasOwnProperty('imageLinks') == false ? "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/pandorahearts/images/a/ad/Not_available.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20141028171337" : volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
    const publishYear = volumeInfo.hasOwnProperty('publishedDate') == false ? volumeInfo['publishedDate'] = "0000" : volumeInfo.publishedDate;

    return (

      <div className="card-container">
        <img src={thumbNail} alt=""/>
        <div className="desc">
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <p>Author: {authors}</p>
          <p>Price: {price}</p>
          <p>Raiting: {averageRating == "0.00" ? "Not available" : averageRating}</p>
          <p>Published: {publishYear == "0000" ? "Not available" : publishYear.substring(0,4)}</p>                        
        </div>
      </div>


    );
}

export default BookCard;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../style/browsing.css';
import Books from '../component/Books';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="flexbox-container">
                <div className="browsing">
                    <Books/>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import './style/browsing.css';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Register from './pages/Register';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Orders from './pages/Orders';
import BookDetails from './pages/BookDetails';
import ShopCart from './pages/ShopCart';
import Profile from './pages/Profile';
//import Books from './component/Books';
import { Route, HashRouter, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';


// NPM RUN CLIENT is the updated src folder, (NPM RUN SERVER/NPM START) runs build in my case which is the old green template
//Use ctrL + C to stop the server
//Always run NPM INSTALL on a newly cloned file
//Do not push updates to master branch, push to your own branch PLZ

//updated file structure on my branch (miguel) 2/17/20
//npm install after downloading/ npm install --save react-bootstrap mighe be needed for BookDetails to work
//npm npm run client to run this package

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <HashRouter>
      <div>
        <NavLink to="/" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
          <h1><i class="material-icons">menu_book</i> GeekText</h1>
        </NavLink>
        <ul className="header">
          <li><NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to="/Login">Login</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to="/Orders">Orders</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to="/BookDetails">Book Details</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to="/Profile">Profile</NavLink></li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/ShopCart">
              <i class="material-icons md-dark md-24">shopping_cart</i>
            </NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className="content">
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/Register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/Orders" component={Orders} />
          <Route path="/BookDetails" component={BookDetails} />
          <Route path="/ShopCart" component={ShopCart} />
          <Route path="/Profile" component={Profile} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  </div>

);

export default App;
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question for better results.

Comment: added the files